# Unable to access http/https svn repositories on mac os despite trying various svn versions

Tags: macos, svn, installation

I get the following error while using svn 1.8.3 on Mac OS X 10.8.4.

svn: E120108: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://xp-dev.com/svn/repo-name'
svn: E120108: Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection.

I have tried many different installations (from source, using macports, binaries) and many different svn versions (1.8.x, 1.7.x) and the problem remains. I wonder if there is some fundamental missing library which is causing the problem. I should mention that I can access svn on my corporate server but not from public server like xp-dev etc.

What is a sure-shot way of getting an svn installation on my machine which can access http svn server? Thanks.

Comment: Even this does not work: git svn clone http://xp-dev.com/svn/repo-name
Initialized empty Git repository in /Desktop/2git/repo-name/.git/
RA layer request failed: OPTIONS of 'http://xp-dev.com/svn/repo-name': could not connect to server (http://xp-dev.com) at /usr/share/git-core/perl/Git/SVN.pm line 141

Comment: can you make sure your svn server is up and running in 'https://xp-dev.com/svn/repo-name' and you are authorised.
Put the url in browser, and use your credential to check.

Comment: Yes, the svn server is up and running. In fact, I have a different mac (Mac book pro running OS X 10.7.5) which has svn 10.7.5. I am able to check out the same repository on this machine. The problem I mentioned above is on my Mac air. And it is not limited to xp-dev, it persists with unfuddle or any http/https based service. However svn+ssh works. Are there cloud based private repositories which give svn+ssh access?

Comment: I think, its due to firewall, though not sure as i am not a mac user.
Try to add an inbound rule for the svn server in your mac book pro.
yes there are online repository available
https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/ 3 user 500mb
https://bitbucket.org/ 5 user unlimited space